# Upgrade R 3.2 to 3.3 using tar.gz file on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: upgrade, r

I am working on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 and I have installed R 3.2.
I need to upgrade to R 3.3 and I tried several options available online with no success. I downloaded the tar.gz file for R 3.3 and I would like to ask how can I use this file in order to accomplish the upgrade.

Many thanks,

Luigi

Answer (score 1):

You downloaded the R source code therefore you need to unpack and compile it:

1. `tar xf R-3.3.1.tar.gz` (filename is depending on the version you have)
2. `cd R-3.3.1`
3. `./configure`
4. Now comes the tricky part. Configure might stop with some error messages and now you need to install some additional packages. On my machine it was

`apt-get install gfortran libreadline-dev bzip2-dev liblzma-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev`

5. If you have errors in running `configure` you need to search the needed packages by your own. Then what I do is for an example `apt-cache search readline dev` because you need the development files of the library. Then restart `configure` to see if it helps.
6. The output line "R is now configured..." shows success, so you can start compiling with a `make`.
7. Hopefully you got no errors you can then install the package with `sudo make install` (you need admin rights to write to `/usr/local/` -> therefore you need `sudo` with your user password)
8. Start your newly compiled package with `/usr/local/bin/R` to be sure you are using the right version.
9. With `sudo make uninstall` you can again delete it from `/usr/local/`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I ran the extraction and configure commands with no errors, but when I ran the installation it did not succeed. I got:

Comment: $ sudo make install
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/lib/R-3.3.1/m4'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'install'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/R-3.3.1/m4'
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/lib/R-3.3.1/tools'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'install'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/R-3.3.1/tools'
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/lib/R-3.3.1/doc'
installing doc ...

Comment: /usr/bin/install: cannot stat 'NEWS.rds': No such file or directory
help2man: can't get `--help' info from ../bin/R
Makefile:43: recipe for target 'R.1' failed
make[1]: *** [R.1] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/R-3.3.1/doc'
Makefile:95: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1

Comment: The line "Nothing to be done for 'install'" looks like you did not run 'make'.